# How to align a div in center respective to the div below it?

Tags: html, css, user-interface

How can I align img in center to the respective to the text below it? The wrapper div is aligned left.

```
<div class="wrapper"> 
 <div class="com-icon">
   <img src="images/IT.png" alt="laptop logo">
 </div>
 <div class="com-text">
    <p>IT Solutions</p>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Try this `.com-icon, .com-text {
    text-align: center;
}` ..

Answer (score 0):

Add another wrapper around the com-icon and com-text. And then align that were you want it. Example below:

```
<div class="wrapper"> 
    <div class="wrapper-inner">
        <div class="com-icon">
            <img src="images/IT.png" alt="laptop logo">
        </div>
        <div class="com-text">
            <p>IT Solutions</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your css file:

```
.wrapper{
  text-align: center;
}
```

or if you just want to check if it's working you can add  the infamous inline style.
This not a recommended method other than just to see if it's OK!

```
<div class="wrapper" style="text-align:center;"> 
 <div class="com-icon">
   <img src="images/IT.png" alt="laptop logo">
 </div>
 <div class="com-text">
    <p>IT Solutions</p>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

make a table

```css
table.center {
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.com-text,
.com-icon {
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrraper">
  <table class="center">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div class="com-icon">
          <img src="image.jpg" alt="laptop logo">
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div class="com-text">
          <p>IT Solutions</p>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```